# How to hide items in Visual Express 2012 for Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, hide

I'm a very early coder and using c# for desktop to start off and I heard I could code for windows phone using c# but it is so different it makes my head spin.

How do I hide a rectangle called "rctSquare1"? I'm used to typing "rctSquare1.Hide();" but that doesn't work and I cant find any answers...

Comment: Some code might help to understand your problem.

Comment: What do you mean? What sort of code would I supply?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
rctSquare1.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
```

Update

What about that?

```
rctSquare1.Opacity = 0;
```

Comment: "visibility.Hidden" did not work. The error message it displayed was: "'System.Windows.Visibility' does not contain a definition for 'Hidden' and no extension method 'Hidden' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Visibility' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: "rctSquare1.Opacity = 0;" worked as well, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Set one of the following [`Visibility`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.visibility%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) values on your element:

Setting it to `Visibility.Hidden` will leave empty space in your window where the element was (similar to `SomeControl.Hide()` in `WinForms`.

> Do not display the element, and do not reserve space for it in layout.

```
rect.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

Alternatively, `Visibility.Collapsed` will actually hide the element and collapse the empty space too. If your element is inside a grid, for example, then setting to `Collapsed` will cause the row to collapse as well *(as long as you aren't setting an explicit height on the row, and there aren't any other elements in the row preventing it from collapsing)*.

> Do not display the element, but reserve space for the element in layout.

```
rect.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
```